# Google sign in ux_mode=redirect unable to pass my own params

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

redirect and popup are working fine, the only difference is `ux_mode=redirect` **cannot send param_to_login to the serverside**, while `ux_mode=popup` **can**

`ux_mode=redirect` example:

```
<div
    id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="my_client_id"
    data-ux_mode="redirect"
    data-login_uri="login_uri"
    data-param_1_to_login="any_value"
    data-param_2_to_login="any_value"
/>
```

`ux_mode=popup` example:

```
<div
    id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="my_client_id"
    data-login_uri="login_uri"
    data-your_own_param_1_to_login="any_value"
    data-your_own_param_2_to_login="any_value"
/>
```

I tried ux_mode=redirect and ux_mode=popup to pass `param_to_login` but it seems ux_mode=redirect is unable to pass parameters.

Question is: I wanted to use the ux_mode=redirect and pass my own params to the serverside, how can i do it?